# Vue.js & Express-gateway CORS request

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, express-gateway

I have a problem with an HTTP request from a Vue.js component to a server with express gateway.
I assume the problem is on Express Gateway because even if the microservice that should receive the request is offline, the error still shows anyway.

The Vue.js code is very simple and is:

```
await this.$http.post('http://localhost:8080/cartItems/',{
                    user_id: this.userId,
                    product_id: this.productId,
                    quantity: productQuantity,
                },{
                    headers:{
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    }
                }).then(response => {
                    Vue.$toast.open({
                        position: 'bottom-right',
                        type: 'success',
                        duration: 3000,
                        message: '--------',
                    });
                })
                .catch(errors => {
                    Vue.$toast.open({
                        position: 'bottom-right',
                        type: 'error',
                        duration: 3000,
                        message: '--------',
                    });
                });
```

The error in console is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/cartItems/' from origin 'http://localhost:10000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The strange thing (strange for me) is that the problem shows up only with POST request but it doesn't with a GET request.

I configured the gateway with cors policy (see below) following the documentation, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
policies:
  - cors

......

pipelines:
  cart:
    apiEndpoints:
      - cart-view-update-delete
      - cart-add
      - cart-my
    policies:
      - cors:
          - action:
              origin: '*'
              methods: ['HEAD','PUT','PATCH','POST','DELETE']
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: cart
              changeOrigin: true
```

Comment: are you adding response headers to a request? i.e. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` - that's not how CORS works ... the client can't tell the server to allow access, the server tells the client it may have access - in fact by adding that header, you trigger a **pre-flight** - and your server doesn't like pre-flights obviously ... see how the error states *Response to **preflight** request*

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Even removing the "headers" options on request, the error is the same on the console. Honestly, I added these lines in a desperate attempt.

Comment: well, you're probably sending content-type json or something, so that too triggers a pre-flight - seems your server config doesn't include pre-flight settings (OPTIONS request) - I don't know anything about this express gateway so maybe you need to red some documentation regarding pre-flight and OPTIONS request in the documentation of express gaeway

Comment: check what headers your request is sending. if it includes `content-type` then you need to configure `allowedHeaders` in the cors policy configuration - as per [documentation](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/policies/cors/)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, here's the correct option for **cors**

```
   - cors:
      - action:
          origin: true
          credentials: true
          methods: 'HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,GET'
          exposedHeaders : ['allowed-custom-header']
          allowedHeaders :  '*'
          preflightContinue : false
          optionsSuccessStatus  : 204
```